# 3d surface plot in browser

Tags: javascript, python, 3d, web

I have a python web server (cherrypy), and I want the user to be able to compute certain surfaces of this precise type. This is what I am able to generate from user input. He gives me some parameters, I compute my things, generate it as PNG on the server (matplotlib/numpy) and send it back through a JQuery load.

[image]

Problem is, this is pretty lame, and the surfaces can have various aspects. I'd like to be able to have an actual widget or so that would enable the user to rotate his surface...

My major constraints is that it has to work on IE 7 (8 would be cool as well), and allow the input of the data I compute somehow. I've seen many things on the web that only permit to input parametric functions. What I need is to be able to push in raw data triplets.

I've been looking at several things, Javascript would be the best but I failed to see something in JQuery or equivalents. I did look quite long around WebGL and started implementing stuff...from scratch... but way too long and random behavior in IE sometimes.

Maybe I'm missing out completely on something, on some technology or format that is compatible with my python, but I've spent days before adopting the temporary solution of plotting into PNGs.

Looking forward to reading you guys,
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Can [chrome-frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) be a requirement?

Comment: Well I was thinking about that, one some forum one guy did a nice summary of the best ways to use WebGL, chrome frame was evaluated as a solution as good as IEWebGL. I cannot consider it tough, because I need an install-less approach.. Sorry ;)

Comment: Worth a shot. It [doesn't require admin rights](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/06/introducing-non-admin-chrome-frame.html) anymore, if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, if you need IE7 compatibility, most of the available libraries in JS won't work for you - they require either `canvas` or SVG support. You're left with static images, Flash, or Java applets.

I would look into [processing](http://processing.org/), which has good 3D support and can create Java applets for web use. See [the 3D tutorials](http://processing.org/learning/3d/) for good examples of interactive 3D surfaces.

If you wanted to get fancy, you could potentially also offer [processing.js](http://processingjs.org/) for browsers that support the `canvas` element. This would avoid loading a Java applet for those browsers, making for a slightly smoother UI and removing the Java dependency. You'd need to check for browser compatibility and then load either the applet code or the processing.js code. The upside of this is that you should be able to use exactly the same processing code in both cases.

Comment: That's roughly what I figured, although excanvas.js and IEWebGL do help a little. Could you recommend tools and tips about how to load input in such Flash or Java component ? My concern is how to do so from my python..

Comment: I believe you can use processing's [loadStrings()](http://processing.org/reference/loadStrings_.html) function to load content from a URL on the same site. So you could use python to provide an API for your data in some text-based format.

Comment: I'm looking more into processing.js, although it seems going for that means developing my own surfaces plots... any idea if there's a project rendering things close to what I'm looking for ?

Comment: Not that I know of, but that doesn't mean there isn't one. Processing's strength is custom visualizations, and people tend to use it for idiosyncratic projects. But there might be something here: http://processing.org/reference/libraries/

Comment: As a conclusion, I didn't go to any of those technologies. I'm developing a bespoke applet in Java. I'll leave entry points to specify url from which to get diverse data. I go for that since developing in Java is easy, debug is easy as well in a tool such as Eclipse, and throwing XML to my app will be easy to figure out.

Answer (score 2):

have the python script return the vertices/points of the 3D model in json format then use mrdoob's three.js to create a live, javascript-powered, 3D, webGL model directly in the browser.

Check out three.js here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js

(Look at the amazing examples there for inspiration, you can probably get a hold of mrdoob for insights also...)

EDIT: Oops, just noticed the IE7 requirement. No webGL for IE7 :(. You'll have to use Flash for 3D rendering. EIther that or have your python script create different angles of the view that can be loaded as images in the browser (for example the user clicks on the right button and the next image that loads is rotated at a certain angle to the right).

EDIT: Looks like IEWebGL will enable webGL for IE7!

EIDT: processing.js looks really nice for visualizations too!

Comment: well I found out that IEWebGL works quite nicely on IE7, check the examples here, some are quite nice, but then digging in the code isn't nice, lacks comments, but well the site is still pretty young : iewebgl.com/

Comment: I think your best bet is to figure out how json works and how to retrieve it from your server with an HTTP GET or POST request.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for something similar (contour plots in JS) and came across one that looks like it works in IE6 (using excanvas): http://code.google.com/p/javascript-surface-plot/

It uses the Google Visualization API:

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
for (var i = 0; i < numCols; i++) {
    data.addColumn('number', 'col' + i);
}
data.addRows(numRows);
var d = 360 / numRows;
var idx = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
        var value = (Math.cos(i * d * Math.PI / 180.0) * Math.cos(j * d * Math.PI / 180.0));
        data.setValue(i, j, value / 4.0);
        tooltipStrings[idx] = "x:" + i + ", y:" + j + " = " + value;
        idx++;
    }
}
```

so maybe you can load that up with your triplet data.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Pre3d. It doesn't use WebGL. It uses canvas element.
here is the example of it http://www.graphycalc.com/

Use explorecanvas to add canvas support to IE.

Comment: The guy who made it didn't add support for IE, maybe there is a hidden reason ?

Comment: By the way, I still have no solution for this. I temporarily switched to Java applets + javascript for events.